# Where to look for data type definitions?

Tags: c, documentation

Is there any reference material like `man` pages that informs on C datatypes? I thought this would give me something, but not:

```
$ man size_t
No manual entry for size_t
$ man -k size_t
size_t: nothing appropriate.
```

Comment: It is in the “The C programming language”— kernighan and ritchie. And on wikipedia  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor. K&R is silent on such datatypes.  You need to look at the C89 and later revisions of the ISO/IEC 9899 C Language standard.  The current standard is ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (aka C18)

Comment: can you try man stdint.h ?

Comment: @taliezin Nothing.